# How to filter db data using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, active-record-query

I have two tables - images and categories who look like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categories_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `file` text NOT NULL,
  `caption` text NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have 4 categories, and I need to filter and to separatly display images of each category

I try like this but it displays all images

```
**Model:**
public function org_filter()//filter categories
    {
        $this->db->select('i.file,i.categories_id,c.id,c.title',false);
        $this->db->from('images as i');
        $this->db->join('categories as c','i.categories_id = c.id','inner');//join tables based on the foreign key
        $this->db->where('c.title','organizers');//set filter 
        $query = $this->db->get();//get data*/
        return $query;
    }

 **Controller**
 $data=array(
    'r_images'   => $this->Gallery_model->org_filter(),
 );

         $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);

  **View**
     <h3 class="svgbg">ORGANIZERS</h3><!--name of the first category-->
    <?php foreach($r_images->result() as $img) : ?>
        <div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <?=img($img->file)?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

So my goal is to make dinamical fetch from db to view.

P.S: Sorry for bad japanese

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code for your solution..

**Category_model.php**

add this function in cagetory model

```
//Model Category
public function get_category(){
   $q = "select * from categories";
   $rs = $this->db->query($q);
   return $rs->result();
}
```

**Gallery_model.php**

add this function in gallary model.

```
//Gallery_model
public function org_filter($categoryId)//filter categories
{
         $q =  "SELECT * FROM images INNER JOIN categories on images.categories_id = categories.id WHERE categories.id =".$categoryId;
         $q = $this->db->query($q)->result();
         return $q;
}
```

**Gallery.php**

following code add in gallery controller.

```
function index()
    {
        $category = $this->dashboard_model->get_category();

        $data = array();
        //Controller
        //$category = $this->Category_model->get_category();
        foreach ($category as $key => $value) {
            $data['category'][$key]['title'] = $value->title;
            $data['category'][$key]['r_images'] = $this->dashboard_model->org_filter($value->id);
        }
        $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
}
```

**main.php**

following code add in view file main.php

```
<h3 class="svgbg">ORGANIZERS</h3><!--name of the first category-->
<?php foreach($category as $img) :?>
<div>
    <?php echo "Category Name: ".$img['title'];?>  <br>
    <?php foreach($img['r_images'] as $imgage) :?>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <?=img($imgage->file)?> <br>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

above all code add your model, controller and view. you can get perfect output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot the where clause, thats why all images are returned.

try to change the function org_filter like this:

```
public function org_filter($categoryId)//filter categories
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('images');
    $this->db->join('categories','images.categories_id = categories.id','inner');//join tables based on the foreign key
    $this->db->where('categories.id',$categoryId);
    $this->db->on('images.id',10);//set filter
    $query = $this->db->get();//get data
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Undefined variable: categoryId